# Ember actions in a nested resource

Tags: ember.js, controller, nested-routes

I'm attempting to add some actions to the nested route of `Publishables` in Ember:

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('publishables', {path: '/publishables'}, function() {
    this.resource('publishable', { path: ':publishable_id' });
  });
});

export default Router;
```

The `Publishables` route:

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    return this.store.find('publishable', { page: params.page });
  }
});
```

The `Publishables` model:

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
  title: DS.attr(),
  description: DS.attr(),

  authors: DS.hasMany('author', { async: true }),
  category: DS.belongsTo('category', { async: true }),

  published: DS.attr(),
  publish_from: DS.attr(),
  slug: DS.attr(),

  contentType: DS.attr()
});
```

The `Publishables` controller:

```
export default Ember.ArrayController.extend({

  actions : {
    preview: function(id) {
      this.transitionToRoute('publishable', id);
    }
  }

});
```

And the `Publishables` template:

```
<h2>Publishables</h2>
{{#each}}
  <p {{action "preview" id}}>{{title}}</p>
{{/each}}

{{outlet}}
```

This works wonderfully. If I click the `{{title}}`, it transitions to `publishable/:id` and the appropriate data is loaded in the `{{outlet}}`.

Now I would like to add some actions to `Publishable`. If I create a `Publishable` controller much like the `Publishables` controller, everything breaks. I believe this is due to `Publishable` being a child of `Publishables`. Can anyone steer me in to the right direction on how to get actions bound in the nested route?

Comment: will you show the code you're using that isn't working?

Comment: It's mainly when i create a `PublishableController` I lose the context of the data being supplied by the model. In the publishable.hbs I lose access to `{{id}}`, `{{title}}`, etc. I'm not sure why this happens? As such I'm unable to create `actions: {}` inside said controller. Technically it should be inheriting from `Publishables` because it's a nested resource, correct?